# Regex: Correctly matching groups with negative lookback

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with this string:

```
qr/I Love Chocolate|And Free Shipping|All (day|night)|please/i;
```

I'm using the following regex pattern:

```
(?:qr\/)?(.*?)(?:\||\/)
```

I'd like to get the following matches back:

```
["I Love Chocolate", "And Free Shipping", "All (day|night)", "please"]
```

However, this is what I actually get back:

```
["I Love Chocolate", "And Free Shipping", "All (day", "night)", "please"]
```

I modified my regex to use a lookback:

```
(?:qr\/)?(?<!All \(day|night\))(.*?)(?:\||\/)
```

However, this still splits the string into `All (day` and `night)`.

How do I adjust the regex so that instead of capturing `All (day` and `night)` as individual strings, I instead get `All (day|night)`?

More generally, the goal here in muggle-speak would be: "Find any groups  delimited by the pipe character, unless the group contains 1 or more pipe characters surrounded by ellipses; in which case, treat that entire string as one group."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex for matching:

```
[^/|(]+(?:\([^)]*\))*
```

**Code:**

```
>>> str = 'qr/I Love Chocolate|And Free Shipping|All (day|night)|please/i'
>>> print re.findall(r'[^/|(]+(?:\([^)]*\))*', str)
['qr', 'I Love Chocolate', 'And Free Shipping', 'All (day|night)', 'please', 'i']
```

Or if you want to discard `qr/` at start and `/i` in the end then use:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'[^/|(]+(?:\([^)]*\))*', re.sub(r'^qr/(.*)/i$', r'\1', str))
['I Love Chocolate', 'And Free Shipping', 'All (day|night)', 'please']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBka56/16)

Answer (score 2):

If it is just about `day` and `night` words around `|` specifically, you can use *negative lookbehind and negative lookahead*:

```
>>> re.split(r"(?<!day)\|(?!night)", s)
['qr/I Love Chocolate', 'And Free Shipping', 'All (day|night)', 'please/i;']
```

---

I'd also remove the `qr/` prefix and `/i` postfix beforehand to keep the split expression simple. For example, this way:

```
>>> s = "qr/I Love Chocolate|And Free Shipping|All (day|night)|please/i;"
>>> s = re.sub(r"^[a-z]+/", "", s)
>>> s = re.sub(r"/[a-z]+;$", "", s)
```

Then, split:

```
>>> re.split(r"(?<!day)\|(?!night)", s)
['I Love Chocolate', 'And Free Shipping', 'All (day|night)', 'please']
```

Comment: The `All (day|night)` is just one of the many similar patterns. So ideally, I'd like to say "Match anything between pipe symbols, unless the match contains 1 or more pipe symbols surrounded by ellipses, in which case treat that whole thing as one group."

Comment: @DirtyPenguin ah, okay, then I think anubhava's solution should cover these, give it a try. I'll see if I can improve mine. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the lookbehind/lookahead examples though :)